# Changing php in a joomla template -- not sure how to fix class appending

Tags: php, templates, joomla

I'm doing some work on joomla (well learning it) I could use a hand. php is not really my expertise. So I don't want to break the site. Here is what I'm trying to do.

http://rcpsus.com/

You see that white bar below the menu. I'm trying to get rid of it.

I've found the offending code. The white bar is part of the #footer..specifically div#block-footer and has a class appended .bg-white which makes the background #fff or white. Normally in most situations I would just hand code out the problems and retool them using individual css rules. But that option isn't available with joomla. I'm not exactly sure how to approach this problem via the php. I've tried removing the code in the

`$colored = ($this['config']->get($pos) != 'white') ? ' bg-colored' : '';
        $this['config']->set($pos, 'bg-'.$this['config']->get($pos).$colored);`

section. However it doesn't appear to fix the problem. If someone could lend me a hand I would be greatful. I included the full document for context below. Thanks in advance.

```
 <?php
/**
* @package   yoo_infinite
* @author    YOOtheme http://www.yootheme.com
* @copyright Copyright (C) YOOtheme GmbH
* @license   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html GNU/GPL
*/

// generate css for layout
$css[] = sprintf('.wrapper { max-width: %dpx; }', $this['config']->get('template_width'));


****// set block css classes
foreach (array("top-a-bg","top-b-bg","main-bg","bottom-a-bg","bottom-b-bg","bottom-c-bg","footer-bg") as $pos) {
    if ($pos == 'footer-bg') {
        $body_bg = 'body-'.$this['config']->get($pos);
    }
    $colored = ($this['config']->get($pos) != 'white') ? ' bg-colored' : '';
    $this['config']->set($pos, 'bg-'.$this['config']->get($pos).$colored);*
}***

// generate css for 3-column-layout
$sidebar_a       = '';
$sidebar_b       = '';
$maininner_width = 100;
$sidebar_a_width = intval($this['config']->get('sidebar-a_width'));
$sidebar_b_width = intval($this['config']->get('sidebar-b_width'));
$sidebar_classes = "";
$rtl             = $this['config']->get('direction') == 'rtl';
$body_config     = array();

// set widths
if ($this['modules']->count('sidebar-a')) {
    $sidebar_a = $this['config']->get('sidebar-a'); 
    $maininner_width -= $sidebar_a_width;
    $css[] = sprintf('#sidebar-a { width: %d%%; }', $sidebar_a_width);
}

if ($this['modules']->count('sidebar-b')) {
    $sidebar_b = $this['config']->get('sidebar-b'); 
    $maininner_width -= $sidebar_b_width;
    $css[] = sprintf('#sidebar-b { width: %d%%; }', $sidebar_b_width);
}

$css[] = sprintf('#maininner { width: %d%%; }', $maininner_width);

// all sidebars right
if (($sidebar_a == 'right' || !$sidebar_a) && ($sidebar_b == 'right' || !$sidebar_b)) {
    $sidebar_classes .= ($sidebar_a) ? 'sidebar-a-right ' : '';
    $sidebar_classes .= ($sidebar_b) ? 'sidebar-b-right ' : '';

// all sidebars left
} elseif (($sidebar_a == 'left' || !$sidebar_a) && ($sidebar_b == 'left' || !$sidebar_b)) {
    $sidebar_classes .= ($sidebar_a) ? 'sidebar-a-left ' : '';
    $sidebar_classes .= ($sidebar_b) ? 'sidebar-b-left ' : '';
    $css[] = sprintf('#maininner { float: %s; }', $rtl ? 'left' : 'right');

// sidebar-a left and sidebar-b right
} elseif ($sidebar_a == 'left') {
    $sidebar_classes .= 'sidebar-a-left sidebar-b-right ';
    $css[] = '#maininner, #sidebar-a { position: relative; }';
    $css[] = sprintf('#maininner { %s: %d%%; }', $rtl ? 'right' : 'left', $sidebar_a_width);
    $css[] = sprintf('#sidebar-a { %s: -%d%%; }', $rtl ? 'right' : 'left', $maininner_width);

// sidebar-b left and sidebar-a right
} elseif ($sidebar_b == 'left') {
    $sidebar_classes .= 'sidebar-a-right sidebar-b-left ';
    $css[] = '#maininner, #sidebar-a, #sidebar-b { position: relative; }';
    $css[] = sprintf('#maininner, #sidebar-a { %s: %d%%; }', $rtl ? 'right' : 'left', $sidebar_b_width);
    $css[] = sprintf('#sidebar-b { %s: -%d%%; }', $rtl ? 'right' : 'left', $maininner_width + $sidebar_a_width);
}

// number of sidebars
if ($sidebar_a && $sidebar_b) {
    $sidebar_classes .= 'sidebars-2 ';
} elseif ($sidebar_a || $sidebar_b) {
    $sidebar_classes .= 'sidebars-1 ';
}

// generate css for dropdown menu
foreach (array(1 => '.dropdown', 2 => '.columns2', 3 => '.columns3', 4 => '.columns4') as $i => $class) {
    $css[] = sprintf('#menu %s { width: %dpx; }', $class, $i * intval($this['config']->get('menu_width')));
}

// load css
$this['asset']->addFile('css', 'css:base.css');
$this['asset']->addFile('css', 'css:layout.css');
$this['asset']->addFile('css', 'css:menus.css');
$this['asset']->addString('css', implode("\n", $css));
$this['asset']->addFile('css', 'css:modules.css');
$this['asset']->addFile('css', 'css:tools.css');
$this['asset']->addFile('css', 'css:system.css');
$this['asset']->addFile('css', 'css:extensions.css');
$this['asset']->addFile('css', 'css:custom.css');
if ($this['config']->get('animation') == '1') $this['asset']->addFile('css', 'css:animation.css');
if (($font = $this['config']->get('font1')) && $this['path']->path("css:/font1/$font.css")) { $this['asset']->addFile('css', "css:/font1/$font.css"); }
if (($font = $this['config']->get('font2')) && $this['path']->path("css:/font2/$font.css")) { $this['asset']->addFile('css', "css:/font2/$font.css"); }
if (($font = $this['config']->get('font3')) && $this['path']->path("css:/font3/$font.css")) { $this['asset']->addFile('css', "css:/font3/$font.css"); }
$this['asset']->addFile('css', 'css:style.css');
if ($this['config']->get('direction') == 'rtl') $this['asset']->addFile('css', 'css:rtl.css');
$this['asset']->addFile('css', 'css:responsive.css');
$this['asset']->addFile('css', 'css:print.css');

// load fonts
$http  = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off') ? 'https' : 'http';
$fonts = array(
    'droidsans' => 'template:fonts/droidsans.css',
    'opensans' => 'template:fonts/opensans.css',
    'opensanslight' => 'template:fonts/opensanslight.css',
    'yanonekaffeesatz' => 'template:fonts/yanonekaffeesatz.css',
    'mavenpro' => 'template:fonts/mavenpro.css',
    'signika' => 'template:fonts/signika.css',
    'titillium' => 'template:fonts/titillium.css',
    'titillium_light' => 'template:fonts/titillium_light.css',
    'droidserifitalic' => 'template:fonts/droidserifitalic.css',
    'artifika' => 'template:fonts/artifika.css',
    'kreon' => 'template:fonts/kreon.css');

foreach (array_unique(array($this['config']->get('font1'), $this['config']->get('font2'), $this['config']->get('font3'))) as $font) {
    if (isset($fonts[$font])) {
        $this['asset']->addFile('css', $fonts[$font]);
    }
}

// set body css classes
$body_classes = ' '.$sidebar_classes.' ';
$body_classes .= ' '.$body_bg.' ';
$body_classes .= $this['system']->isBlog() ? 'isblog ' : 'noblog ';
$body_classes .= $this['config']->get('page_class');

$this['config']->set('body_classes', $body_classes);

// add social buttons
$body_config['twitter'] = (int) $this['config']->get('twitter', 0);
$body_config['plusone'] = (int) $this['config']->get('plusone', 0);
$body_config['facebook'] = (int) $this['config']->get('facebook', 0);

$body_config['style'] = $this['config']->get('style', 'default');

$this['config']->set('body_config', json_encode($body_config));

// add javascripts
$this['asset']->addFile('js', 'js:warp.js');
$this['asset']->addFile('js', 'js:responsive.js');
$this['asset']->addFile('js', 'js:accordionmenu.js');
$this['asset']->addFile('js', 'js:dropdownmenu.js');
$this['asset']->addFile('js', 'js:template.js');

// internet explorer
if ($this['useragent']->browser() == 'msie') {

    // add conditional comments
    $head[] = sprintf('<!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="%s"></script><![endif]-->', $this['path']->url('js:html5.js'));
    $head[] = sprintf('<!--[if IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="%s" /><![endif]-->', $this['path']->url('css:ie8.css'));

}

// add $head
if (isset($head)) {
    $this['template']->set('head', implode("\n", $head));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

figured it out --

/templates/layouts/index.php

removed the #footer -class appending in the relevant section

Comment: please be careful when editing core files, especially in a framework file which it currently is. If a warp(framework) update is released, then your change will be overridden.